# Concrete Mathematics: Clarifying expressing sum in terms of $H_n$ leading to equation 2.14

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, recurrence-relations

In Concrete Mathematics (Knuth, Patashnik, and Graham) we have an intermediate solution to the quick-sort recurrence of

$$
C_n = 2(n + 1)\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k + 1}
$$

Given the sum part of that resembles the Harmonic summation of $\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}$ we can transform the sum part of the intermediate form above to a Harmonic sum thereby providing a "closed form" solution.

The book does this in the following steps

$$
\begin{align}
\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k + 1} &= \sum_{1 \leq k - 1 \leq n}\frac{1}{k} \\
&= \sum_{2 \leq k \leq n+1}\frac{1}{k} \\
&= \left( \sum_{1\leq k \leq n}\frac{1}{k} \right) - \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{n+1} = H_n - \frac{n}{n+1}
\end{align} 
$$

I *think* the $\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{n+1}$ terms are to "trim" the resultant the sum so that we can use $H_n$ in its natural form with clean boundary conditions. So $-\frac{1}{1}$ removes the "start" and $\frac{1}{n+1}$ adds on what the $n+1$ boundary condition would have done. Is this what is happening?

And, if you'll indulge me, add on a follow-up question. The eventual, closed form solution is then presented as follows (2.14 in book)

$$
C_n = 2(n + 1)H_n - 2n
$$

Where do they get $2n$ from? I would have thought the eventual closed form would then be $C_n = 2(n+1)H_n - \frac{n}{n+1}$ Obviously 2.14 is correct though; maybe I'm being insufficiently creative in my algebraic manipulations (or need more coffee).

Comment: Nope: the $2(n+1)$ also distributes to the $-\frac n{n+1}$ part of the sum.

Comment: Ah ok, so it could be viewed as $2(n+1)(H_n - \frac{n}{n+1})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+1} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n+1}.$$  So if we compare this to $$H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n},$$ we can see that in the first sum we are missing the first term $1$, and we have an extra last term, $\frac{1}{n+1}$.  Therefore, $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+1} = H_n - 1 + \frac{1}{n+1}.$$  Then $$\begin{align}
C_n &= 2(n+1) \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+1} \\ &= 2(n+1) \left( H_n - 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \right) \\ &= 2(n+1)H_n - 2(n+1) + 2 \\ &= 2(n+1)H_n - 2n. \end{align}$$

Comment: To close the loop: My confusion was from the fact I did not realise I needed to distribute the $2(n+1)$ to the $-\frac n{n+1}$ part as well. I was just multiplying it with $H_n$